# How to start tomcat using maven in debug mode

Tags: maven, tomcat, maven-plugin

I have found [maven plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/) to start tomcat.

Do Maven have any plugin to start Tomcat in debug mode?

Comment: You should specify which ide (eclipse/netbeans/?) you want to attach your debugger. For eclipse, https://www.google.com/search?q=maven+tomcat+eclipse+debug

Comment: This seems to be the answer to you're question: http://tarique.wordpress.com/2010/09/10/remote-debugging-with-maven-tomcat-plugin/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're using Eclipse and you're running Maven externally (not using M2Eclipse) then you can use whatever command line command you usually use but use `mvnDebug` instead of `mvn`.

As an example, I run the tomcat plugin under the `"run"` profile so my normal command is:

```
    mvn clean install -Prun
```

This uses the `<maven-dir>/bin/mvn` script but to run in debug mode, simply substitute `<maven-dir>/bin/mvnDebug` in.

```
    mvnDebug clean install -Prun
```

If `mvnDebug` isn't on your PATH then you might have to use the full path to it (or create a link from a directory on your path, like `/usr/bin`, to it), e.g:

```
    /path/to/maven-dir/mvnDebug clean install -Prun
```

I'm using maven 3.0.5 and the `mvnDebug` script comes out of the box. If you look inside it then you'll see it basically does what *Titi Wangsa Bin Damhore* says, but you'll note that `suspend=y` is used so the JVM waits for you to connect your debugger before continuing:

```
    MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000"
```

This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: `mvn clean tomcat7:run` with the correct `MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS` allows you to connect as a 'Remote' debugging session in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

we can cheat.
use java opts

```
in *IX
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044"
```

then run your maven,
it should go to debug mode